# splash:set_viewport_full() works fine in localhost whereas when I run the scrapy code it saves only half the image

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I am new to Scrapy-Splash and I want to take a screenshot of the entire web page. For example 'https://stackoverflow.com/'.
In the lua script I have added the below code-

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

I am able to see a full webpage screenshot in the Splash loaclhost.[Here is the image. I have not downloaded it. I want to just show that it works fine here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5MdQ.jpg)

Whereas I want to directly save this in my local. As in instead of manually downloading the images from Splash localhost, I want to save them locally via scrapy. So I have written the below code in Scrapy-Splash-

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    
    def start_requests(self):
        url='https://stackoverflow.com/'
        splash_args = {
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1,
            'wait':0.5
        }
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)

    def parse_result(self, response):
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        filename = 'stackoverflow.png'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
```

When this image is downloaded I see the image is cropped out. [Here is the screenshot of the cropped image after running the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbROR.png).

When I run this code I get a 200 success as below- So that means the code is running via splash localhost.

```
Crawled (200) <GET https://stackoverflow.com/ via http://localhost:8050/render.json> (referer: None)
```

I have attached both images. Once again I am new to Scrapy-Splash. Please help me find a way to fix this issue? Thanks.